# Processing SSAS objects

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssas

We are facing issues on processing SSAS objects using our C# based tool, which let us to 'customize' the way objects are processsed upon a business rule. Basically, the tool runs the following steps:

1) Iterates on database's Dimensions to process (or not) each one on Full/Update mode, according parameters;

2) Iterates on database's Cubes, in order to iterate its Measure Groups, in order to iterate its Partitions to process (or not) each one on Full/Add mode, according parameters;

In this case, we are assuming parameters to let the Dimensions being processed on **Update** mode as well as Partitions being processed on **Full** mode. So, except by Database and Cubes objects, remaining objects are successfuly processed by application and hence Cubes and Database states are 'Processed' too.

The problem appears when browsing a cube which has a boolean Dimension. Its named query is very simple, it just brings the following result:

- **0** - 'False'
- **1** - 'True'
- **null** - 'Undefined'

Since there is no **'null'** value on collected data, analysis should display only **'True'** or **'False'** labels. However, **'Undefined'** option is taking place of **'False'** options.

What could be happening? If we process entire database on **Full** mode by SSMS, the analysis seems to be correct. However, we have built the tool to automate and do the appropriate process. Does our approach violates some implicit processing rule, like priority order?

Thank you all,

Comment: Do you intend to match the null key of the dimension with a null value in the foreign key  column of the fact table? I do not think this will work, nulls do not link to nulls.

Comment: @FrankPl Yes, that's what we have planned. Thank you for the tip, it could answer future questions. For the moment, we still don't know what may be producing that mistaken analysis when processing objects from the tool.

Comment: Analysis Services does not behave like relational databases with nulls in some places: E. g. `IIf(x = 0, y, z)` or `IIf(x = "", y, z)` will evaluate to `y` if `x` is `null`. Hence, maybe there is something similar happening in your partial cube processing. As this is not really reliable, I just try to have all columns except for those only used for measures `not null`, avoiding many ambiguous cases in Analysis Services.

Comment: We have noted that SSMS shows processed objects in a specific order on the Process window: some dimensions seems to be processed before measure groups, and then remaining dimensions are finally processed. That's why we guess there is an implicit rule of processing order, which is not accomplished by processing all dimensions before partitions.

Comment: The display order of items in the Process window is somehow random, maybe the order in which you created them. However, if you issue a `process database`, AS normally uses several execution threads in parallel, but takes care to always process dimensions before any measure group referencing them. Otherwise, the processing order is arbitrary.

Comment: @FrankPl Actually, the issue is fully related with the null key of Dimension. At first analysis, we had no "null" values on fact table, just "true" or "false". So, we tried to input some "nulls" to check if SSAS produces the correct analysis when processing it from SSMS, and voilá: all these "null" entries were aggregated upon "false" entries. So, regardless the way (and tool) we use to process, any analysis which refers to that Dimension is broken. To fix that, we just changed correlation keys to (null > 0), (false > 1) and (true > 2). Thank you.